# xuggler issue with some processors type

Tags: java, processor, xuggler, bridge

I've developed an application that uses xuggler libraries on my laptop with an Intel DualCore processor, anything seems to works fine.
However now I need to setup my application on a server that has an Intel Xeon E3-1230v2 processor and everytimes I run the application I get an error on native libraries:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000013e96520, pid=1724, tid=3804
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C [xuggle5326780242083232878.dll+0x736520] Java_com_xuggle_ferry_FerryJNI_SWIGRefCountedTesterUpcast+0x66f005
#
# Core dump written. Default location: D:\tomcat\hs_err_pid1724.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
# http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I've invested so much time on this project and I really need this to work on the server, I found online xuggler 5.5 that should resolve the issue, but I still get the error.
For what I've seen online this is an issue with some processors type like Ivy Bridge, is there anything I can do to make xuggler work on my machine?

Comment: I have same issue during mp4 video read....did you have get any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I rewrote anything and I switched to ffmpeg.exe, It was way easier than dealing with Xuggler, I've made a blog post about it if it can be of any help : [link](http://pievisdev.blogspot.it/2013/08/transcoding-and-media-modification-java.html)